# How to convert "12,4" to decimal en-Us culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I have a decimal value ("133,3") stored in string column in the database, in norway culture.

after that user changed the regional setting to english-Us. when I convert "133,3" to decimal using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, getting invalid value or error.

is there any best way to handle this scenario in **C#** application?

regards,
Anand

Comment: Can you be explicit? is that meant to be 133 decimal-point 3, or 1333...?

Comment: check this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831727/c-sharp-decimal-parse-issue-with-commas

Comment: "133,3" in Norwagian culture comma is used as decimal separator.

Answer (score 21):

Regardless of the system culture, if you specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` you *won't* be able to parse "133,3" as a decimal to 133.3. The same is true for US English.

You *could* just specify a Norwegian culture when parsing the value (using the overload of  [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) which takes an `IFormatProvider`), or (preferrably) change the field in the database to reflect the real data type (a decimal number) instead.

Comment: +1 - Yes. Only ever use culture specific code when passing data to/from the user e.g. by screen , email, print etc. A standard decimal in the database would be far better as this would allow code to more easily cope with changes in culture.

Answer (score 11):

Do you referred to [Convert.ToDecimal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw.aspx), it says like

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] values = { "123456789", "12345.6789", "12 345,6789",
                          "123,456.789", "123 456,789", "123,456,789.0123",
                          "123 456 789,0123" };
      CultureInfo[] cultures = { new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                 new CultureInfo("fr-FR") }; 

      foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("String -> Decimal Conversion Using the {0} Culture",
                           culture.Name);
         foreach (string value in values)
         {
            Console.Write("{0,20}  ->  ", value);
            try {
               Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(value, culture));
            }
            catch (FormatException) {
               Console.WriteLine("FormatException");
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
      }                     
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried it with: "en-US" and "de-DE" -----
1.234,56: US: FormatException; DE: 1234.56 -> OK -----
1,234.56: US: 1234.56; DE: FormatException -> OK ----- 
234.56: US: 234.56; DE: 23456 -> Not OK -----
234,56: US: 23456; DE: 234.56 -> Not OK -----
Sorry, without line breaks it's a little bit confusing :/

Answer (score 9):

If you know the culture that was in use when persisting the value, you can use it when parsing it, i.e.:

```
Convert.ToDecimal("133,3", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("no"));
```

Of course, you are probably better off changing how the data is stored in the database, to use a floating point number of some form.

Answer (score 6):

```
Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text, new CultureInfo("uk-UA")).ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 2):

This solves your problem: .ToString(New CultureInfo("en-US"))

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's helpful

```
double _number = 12536,8;

CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

return _number.ToString("N", us);
```

Answer (score -1):

used below code to fix my issue. I just hard coded the previous currency decimal part. may not be generic. but solved my problem.

```
public static decimal? ToDecimal1(this string source)
    {
        CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Trim1()))
            return null;
        else
            return Convert.ToDecimal(source.Replace(",", ".").Trim(), usCulture);
    }
```