# asp.net core 2.0 bind model with decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've been looking for a solution to this case for hours, and I did not find anything that worked out for me.

Here we use the comma for decimal separator, and when I send a value like "15,50", in my controller I get the value of the model as "1550", and it only makes sense if I send "15.50".

I covered the following topics, and nothing worked.

[Set CultureInfo in Asp.net Core to have a . as CurrencyDecimalSeparator instead of ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442444/set-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-core-to-have-a-as-currencydecimalseparator-instead)

[Aspnet Core Decimal binding not working on non English Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737607/aspnet-core-decimal-binding-not-working-on-non-english-culture)

I am sending the form with ajax, using the `$form.serializeArray()` as below:

```
function getFormData(xform) {
    var $form = $('#' + xform);
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function (n, i) {
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });    
    return indexed_array;
}
```

send:

```
function PostFormAjax(controller, metodo, params, redir, divacao, reloadgrid) {

    if (params != null) {
        var formData = new FormData();

        var json = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(params));
        $(json).each(function (i, val) {
            $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                console.log(k + " : " + v);
                formData.append(k, v);
            });
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + controller + '/' + metodo,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            AjaxFim(metodo, data, redir, divacao, reloadgrid);
        }
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GravaProduto([FromBody] Produtos produto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         //produto.Valorcusto is 1550 and not 15,50 as it was posted
         //produto.Valorvenda is 1550 and not 15,50 as it was posted
        }
    }
```

My Model.cs

```
public partial class Produtos
{
    public int Cod { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Valorcusto { get; set; }
    public decimal Valorvenda { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to make a replace in **`formData.append(k, v.replace(',', '.'));`** and also does not work, I also would not know which field is a decimal.

What do I have to do? because I'm lost, what should have been simpler became more complicated.

What I did to keep working until I found a solution was:

Wear a mask according to my regional setting:

```
$('.stValor').mask("#.###.##0,00", { reverse: true });
```

And before posting the form, I switch to the accepted formatting:

```
$('#fCadAltProd').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.stValor').mask("#,###,##0.00", { reverse: true });
        //Ajax post here
    }
});
```

Comment: just write a custom model binder, instead of using culture info parse the string value as your decimal see this [article](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/)

Comment: Off topic, but you can [pass a `form` element to the `FormData` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and it will fill with all of your form elements automatically.

Comment: `formData.append(k, v.replace(',', '.'))` should have worked if the value was "15,50". I could see it not working if the value was `1.150,50`, since you'd also have to replace `.` with `,`, maybe with something like `v.replace(/[,.]/g, (c) => c == "." ? "," : ".")`.

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer to How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309230). You'd still need to identify which are numbers, but that could be done with a simple regex like `/^[\d,.]+$/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this plugin [jquery.serializeToJSON](https://github.com/raphaelm22/jquery.serializeToJSON/blob/master/README.md)
and change your **getFormData()** function to

```
function getFormData(xform) {
    var $form = $('#' + xform);
    var obj = $form.serializeToJSON({
        parseFloat: {
            condition: ".stValor,.stQnt,.stDesconto",
            nanToZero: true,
            getInputValue: function (i) {
                return i.val().split(".").join("").replace(",", "."); 
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

parseFloat.getInputValue: function(){}, By default, returns the input value without commas, not an error occurs in conversion. if your location uses comma for decimal separation, for example in German or Brazil, you can change to

```
function(i){ 
    return i.val().split(".").join("").replace(",", "."); 
}
```

This will do all the work for you.

Comment: this is definitely a bad way

Answer (score 5):

> Here we use the comma for decimal separator, and when I send a value like "15,50", in my controller I get the value of the model as "1550", and it only makes sense if I send "15.50".

Create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) using [the Norwegian culture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341847/1108891), because Norway also uses the comma decimal separator. You might also want to specify certain [multiple allowed number styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is one that still needs to have error handling. It gives you the basic idea, though, and you can build on it from here. What I would do it copy most of the logic from [the built-in `DecimalModelBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/17d2545b557863955cb5838fa16c6318931ac659/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/DecimalModelBinder.cs).

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AspNetCorePlayground.Models
{
    public class MyFirstModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext
                .ValueProvider
                .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("no"); // Norwegian

            decimal.TryParse(
                valueProviderResult.FirstValue,
                // add more NumberStyles as necessary
                NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                cultureInfo,
                out var model);

            bindingContext
                .ModelState
                .SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);    
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Then decorate your class like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders;

namespace AspNetCorePlayground.Models
{
    public class MyFirstModelBinderTest
    {
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyFirstModelBinder))]
        public decimal SomeDecimal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tested it on a controller:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public IActionResult TestMyFirstModelBinder(MyFirstModelBinderTest model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: did not work either, I'm passing the post via ajax, and getting the complete template

Comment: I did not test via get, implemented in my project, and the post kept coming without a decimal separator, without "." or ","

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for only HTTP POST support and not HTTP GET support. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I need to send the form with HTTP POST and AJAX.