# Int32.Parse vs Single.Parse - ("1,234") and ("1,2,3,4"). Why do int and floating point types parse separator chars differently?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, floating-point, int

In C#:

This throws a `FormatException`, which seems like it shouldn't:

```
Int32.Parse("1,234");
```

This does not, which seems normal:

```
Single.Parse("1,234");
```

And surprisingly, this parses just fine:

```
Single.Parse("1,2,3,4"); //Returns 1234
```

---

My local culture is EN-US, so `,` is the default thousands separator char.

**Main question:** Why the inconsistency?

Also: Why does `Parse("1,2,3,4")` work?  It appears to just be removing all instances of the local separator char before parsing.  I know there would be extra runtime overhead in a regex check or something like that, but when would the numeric literal "1,2,3,4" not be a typo?

---

Related:
[C# Decimal.Parse issue with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831727/c-sharp-decimal-parse-issue-with-commas?lq=1)

Comment: Interesting.. `Single.Parse("1,2,3,4", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);` also outputs `1234`.

Comment: There is no inconsistency here. `Int32.Parse()` defaults to `NumberStyles.Integer` for its second argument, which does not support the thousands separator. On the other hand, `Single.Parse()` defaults to `NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands`, which, well, allows thousands separators. See the Remarks section in [the documentation for the latter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb.aspx).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, the problem is third example. No need to explain first or second. Can you explain why `"1,2,3,4"` is parsed as `1234` value? I am now scared for my user input fields.. for all of them!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would still argue that there is inconsistency between the parsing defaults for `Int32` and `Single`.  The fact that the inconsistency is _explainable_ does not make them consistent.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That seems to be the very definition of inconsistency.

Comment: There is an inevitable inconsistency: ints do not support fractional digits.

Comment: For the third example, the parser just removes thousands separators from the string - this is a [known "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831727) of the parser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The s parameter contains a number of the form:
>
> [ws][sign]digits[ws]
>
> ---
>
> The *s* parameter is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Integer style. In addition to decimal digits, only leading and trailing spaces together with a leading sign are allowed.

That's it, *NumberStyles.Integer* disallows the *Parse* method to use the thousands separator, whereas *[Single.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* uses by default *NumberStyles.Float* and *NumberStyles.AllowThousands*. You can change this behaviour by specifiying the second argument as *NumberStyles*:

```
Int32.Parse("1,234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands); //works
```

*Single.Parse* ignores the grouping and doesn't use culture-specific *[NumberGroupSizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx)* at all, and only determines if the character is a group or decimal separator. The group sizes are used only when formatting numbers.

Answer (score 11):

For the **first case**, from [Microsoft Source Code Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,a438016f815a35c3), by default `Int32.Parse` implements [NumberStyles.Integer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs,2e8a2ade4d29a578) but not `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`

```
public static int Parse(String s) {
    return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

Thus *any* comma separator is not allowed. This:

```
Int32.Parse("1,234");
```

or

```
Int32.Parse("1.234");
```

will both be wrong. In *any* culture.

To fix it, `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` must be added to the `NumberStyles` which will allow "1,234" to be parsed in `EN-US` culture:

```
Int32.Parse("1,234", NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

But

```
Int32.Parse("1.234", NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Will still `throw` an `Exception`.

---

For the **second case**, according to [Microsoft Code Source Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,44a5d69d834baba6), the default style for `Single.Parse` is:

```
public static float Parse(String s) {
    return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

Which allows [thousands separator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs,f9a668507cbae7ec). And `","` is recognized as thousand separator in `EN-US` culture, for `Single.Parse` and thus you get the second case parsed correctly

```
Single.Parse("1,234"); //OK
```

And obviously "1.234" will also be correct, except that "." is not recognized as thousand separators but decimal separator.

---

As for the **third case**, [Internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,9a5e26b13c916503), `Single.Parse` calls `TryStringToNumber`, and [Parse.Number](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,04291cc3a0b10032) which would simply ignore the thousand separators. Thus you get:

```
Single.Parse("1,2,3,4"); //Returns 1234
```

Because it is equivalent as

```
Single.Parse("1234"); //Returns 1234
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP say `Int32.Parse("1,234");` throws a `FormatException` though?

Answer (score 2):

mine is es-ES
On these . is the default thousands separator char, and "," the separate character between int and double
So 
any parse like "1.2.3,4" gives me "123,40" ( 123.40 on US )
If i put the "." before the "," like "123,4.3" it gives error
but, the same way the questions says, if i put "1.2.3.4" gives me "1234"
So, may be it is a functionality of the .net itself.